# 0x Swap Failed , brownie integration

Tags: 0x

I've one error when, swapping ERC20 -> ERC20 with 0x API, the swap failed , previoulsy was getting an error when fetching from etherscan , but manage it to work by calling contract from abi with brownie. I'm getting this error

```
        dai.approve(zap.address, amount, {"from": user1})
>       zap.zapIn(dai.address, crv.address, amount, target.address, dataSwap, {"from": user1})
E       brownie.exceptions.VirtualMachineError: revert: Error Swapping Tokens 1
E       Trace step -1, program counter 2560:
E         File "contracts/zap/Zap.sol", line 85, in Zap._fillQuote:    
E           uint256 initBal = _getBalance(_toTokens);
E           require(approvedTargets[_swapTarget], "Target not Autorizhed");
E           (bool success, ) = _swapTarget.call{ value: valueToSend }(swapData);
E           require(success, "FAIL");
E           uint256 finalBal = _getBalance(_toTokens);
E       
E           amtBought = finalBal - initBal;
```

and here is an implementation of the function fillQuote that deals with the 0x-API

```
function _fillQuote(
        address _fromTokens,
        address _toTokens,
        uint256 _amount,
        address _swapTarget,
        bytes memory swapData
    ) internal returns (uint256 amtBought) {
        if(_fromTokens == _toTokens) {
            return _amount;
        }

        if(_fromTokens == address(0) && _toTokens == wethTokenAddress) {
            IWETH(wethTokenAddress).deposit{value: _amount}();
            return _amount;
        }

        uint256 valueToSend;
        if(_fromTokens == address(0)) {
            valueToSend = _amount;
        } else {
            _approveToken(_fromTokens, _swapTarget);
        }

        uint256 initBal = _getBalance(_toTokens);
        require(approvedTargets[_swapTarget], "Target not Autorizhed");
        (bool success, ) = _swapTarget.call{ value: valueToSend }(swapData);
        require(success, "FAIL");
        uint256 finalBal = _getBalance(_toTokens);

        amtBought = finalBal - initBal;

       
    }
```

Comment: Was thinking , it will work if I approve before, but still failing

Answer (score 1):

What is on line 85? Is it actually failing on `require(success, "FAIL");`?

A couple things to look out for:

1. You should also be passing in either the `value` or `protocolFee` fields returned by the quote response to your contract. If the quote includes a limit order, there will be a protocol fee (in ETH) that needs to be attached to the swap call for the swap to succeed. The `value` field from the response includes both this fee and any ETH you're selling. Alternatively, you can just pass in `protocolFee` and add that to `valueToSend` in `_fillQuote()`.
2. The contract executing the swap call will need a payable fallback for any ETH bought or protocol fees refunded.
3. Protocol fees scale with the effective gas price of the transaction. When you ask for a quote, you should use the `gasPrice` in the response (or lower), or else you run the risk of not passing in enough ETH to cover the protocol fee at a higher gas price.
4. Fiddle with a higher gas limit. The quote response returns a suggested gas limit, but this is usually a pretty inaccurate guess unless you pass in `takerAddress` to the request (in which case it is quite accurate). However, since you are swapping from a contract instead of an EOA, our more accurate gas estimation will fail. So you will have to scale the `gas` response field by a factor that works for your use case.

Comment: ```require(success, "FAIL");``` is the requirement on line 85, I've update the transaction call with gasPrice , also tried to use the existing example on github with weth and DAI but I always get the same error

Comment: Can you provide the values for all the parameters going into `_fillQuote()`?